# Use variable as the name of an array and get one of its elements in bash

Tags: bash

How can I access an element of an array in bash using a variable as its name? The idea is that I want to select the array that I want by passing its name as an argument when I run my script. So I was thinking I could do something like this something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

arrName=$1

g=(1 32)
g5=(5 32)
m=(1 12)
m15=(1 12)

echo "${!arrName[0]}"
echo "${!arrName[1]}"
```

But while this prints the first element of the array, it fails to print the second one. E.g.:

```
./myScript g
```

returns:

```
1

# The second line just has a new line character
```

Can you please explain what is going on as well as the proper way to do this (if any)?

Comment: `declare -n arrName="$1"` to create a *nameref* then get rid of `'!'` in your `"${!arrName[0]}"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indirection involving array elements requires a temporary variable whose value is the name of the array *plus* the desired index.

```
arrName=$1

g=(1 32)
g5=(5 32)
m=(1 12)
m15=(1 12)

tmp0="$arrName[0]"
tmp1="$arrName[1]"
echo "${!tmp0}"
echo "${!tmp1}"
```

That said, namerefs are easier to follow when available.

Comment: Thank you! My version of bash doesn't support namerefs so this is the right solution for my particular case.

Answer (score 1):

Indirection does not work with array names. You need to create a *nameref* using `declare -n arrName="$1"` and then remove the `'!'` from your `echo` statements, e.g.

```
#!/bin/bash
declare -n arrName="$1"

g=(1 32)
g5=(5 32)
m=(1 12)
m15=(1 12)

echo "${arrName[0]}"
echo "${arrName[1]}"
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
bash nr.sh g
1
32
```